# How to convert sc spreadsheet to Excel?

Tags: excel

> The  spreadsheet calculator sc is based on rectangular tables much like
>          a financial spreadsheet.  When invoked it presents  you  with  a  table
>          organized  as  rows  and  columns  of cells.  If invoked without a file
>          argument, the table is initially empty.  Otherwise file is read in (see
>          the  Get  command  below).   Each  cell  may  have associated with it a
>          numeric value, a label string, and/or  an  expression  (formula)  which
>          evaluates to a numeric value or label string, often based on other cell
>          values.

How to convert sc spreadsheet to Excel format?

Comment: Not really an answer but still: if you open the file with `sc`, and save it again using `W<filename.txt>`, it'll be saved in text format. From there it shouldn't be too difficult to open it in Excel (provided it's just data, not formulas and macros).

Answer (score 1):

Gnumeric often installs with a companion application called ssconvert. Ssconvert is designed to convert via command line from one type of spreadsheet file to another. I don't think it can output an SC file, but in can input one. So the command: ssconvert something.sc something.xls should convert an scfile to xls format.
If you don't have Gnumeric installed, maybe installing it will give the solution. If your Gnumeric doesn't install with the ssconvert utility, note that Gnumeric can load SC files and output  .xls files.